# Deduplicating repetitive code in React stateless functions / components

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have quite some stateless React components and all of them contain the same (duplicated) code.

Example:

```
export const Foo = (props) => {
  const [submitted, setSubmitted] = useState(false);
  const form = useForm({ values: props.settings });

  const validated = props.callbacks.validate(form);
  const validations = {
    ...validated,
    submitted,
  };

  return (
    ... my Foo component ...
  );
};

export const Bar = (props) => {
  const [submitted, setSubmitted] = useState(false);
  const form = useForm({ values: props.settings });

  const validated = props.callbacks.validate(form);
  const validations = {
    ...validated,
    submitted,
  };

  return (
    ... my Bar component ...
  );
};
```

Is there a way I can deduplicate somehow the duplicated code? (the `set/submitted` setter/getter, the `form` definition and the `validated` / `validations` definitions).

PS: I need the components to be stateless, so I can't transform the components into a class and inherit from a base class.

Comment: Your component is already stateful since it's using `useState`. The fact that it is a function has nothing to do with having a state or not, now thanks to hooks.

Comment: @EmileBergeron Indeed. Thanks for the correction!

Comment: What you need is to extract the repeated code into [a custom hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-custom.html).

Comment: In order to reduce duplicated code, can't you just set the ````state```` in the ````parent```` container and work from there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As discussed in comments, a custom hook is perfect here. You'll of course need to adjust the "API surface" of your hook depending on what `<MyFoo />` and `<MyBar />` need:

```
function useSubmittedValidation({ settings, callbacks }) {
  const [submitted, setSubmitted] = useState(false);
  const form = useForm({ values: settings });
  const validated = callbacks.validate(form);
  const validations = {
    ...validated,
    submitted,
  };
  return { form, submitted, setSubmitted, validations };
}

export const Foo = (props) => {
  const { submitted, setSubmitted, form, validations } = useSubmittedValidation(props);
  return <MyFoo />;
};

export const Bar = (props) => {
  const { submitted, setSubmitted, form, validations } = useSubmittedValidation(props);
  return <MyBar />;
};
```

Answer (score -1):

One great way to extract a lot of duplicated code is through HOCs (Higher Order Components). For example in order to extract the state you can do like this:

```
const withSubmittedState = (WrappedComponent) => {
  const Component = () => {
  const [submitted, setSubmitted] = useState(false);
    return <WrappedComponent />;
  };

  return Component;
};
```

And then you export your Foo component like this:

```
const Foo = (props) => {
  const form = useForm({ values: props.settings });

  const validated = props.callbacks.validate(form);
  const validations = {
    ...validated,
    submitted,
  };

  return (
    ... my Foo component ...
  );
};

export withSubmittedState(Foo);
```

And Bar component like this:

```
const Bar = (props) => {
  const form = useForm({ values: props.settings });

  const validated = props.callbacks.validate(form);
  const validations = {
    ...validated,
    submitted,
  };

  return (
    ... my Bar component ...
  );
};

export withSubmittedState(Bar);
```

Now Foo and Bar components both have a `submitted` state.
Note that depending on the logic of your application you might need to pass this state down as props to the `WrappedComponent`.

Comment: Why would you use that over a custom hook? What if the state isn't supposed to be shared? What about the Law of Demeter violation in the OP's code?

Comment: I have not used it over a custom hook, I just extracted `useState` hook which is not a custom hook. And this is supposed to to set an example how to extract duplicated code, this is not applicable in each and every situation.

Comment: Also, you're not showing the state used in HOC. How that state should be used? This is a bit confusing.

Comment: It really depends on the logic of the application. I would have written a more concrete answer if the question was more specific.

Comment: When answering, you should also take care of the future visitors as well but not just to OP's code. So, if you modify your answer, then it will be better.